# No route matches {:action =>"destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, destroy

I'm getting the following error when trying to destroy a user's vote on a "contribution":

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"contribution_votes", 
                  :id=>#<ContributionVote contribution_id: 8245, user_id: 40>}
```

But have no idea why. Here is the button sending the request

```
<%= button_to "undo voteup!", 
        contribution.contribution_votes.find_by_user_id(current_user), 
        :method => :delete, :class => 'contribution_vote undo' %>
```

Here's the "destroy" action in the controller:

```
def destroy
    @vote = current_user.contribution_votes.find(params[:id])
    @vote.destroy


    @contribution = Contribution.find_by_id(@vote.contribution_id)


    @contribution_decrement = @contribution.decrement(:votes)

if @vote.destroy and @contribution_decrement.save
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    format.js
 end 
 else 
        redirect_to :back         

 end
end
```

(some redundancy here I know, but it's to be filled in at a later date)

And here's the setup in routes.rb

```
resources :contribution_votes, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

Can anyone help? I suspect the answer's obvious but I can't find it anywhere on SO.

Comment: Can you show us the generated html of the button?

Comment: @John - I'm very new to rails so don't really know how to go about remedying that (I'm also not sure why what I'm using is a nested resource, but will go look it up). Is there any way I can set the controller explicitly? And why would it not be looking for the correct controller? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you restarted the server after you have changed the routes?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in view to (I think it will help):

```
<%= button_to "undo voteup!", 
    contribution_votes_path(current_user.id),
    :method => :delete, :class => 'contribution_vote undo' %>
```

.. by the way: type `rake routes` in your console and verify that you use right route path (I can mistake).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - probably because the controller tries to find the contribution_vote with id=user.id. The form needs to pass both current_user.id and contribution.id to identify the right contribution_vote to be deleted...

Comment: Routes also seem to be fine: `contribution_vote DELETE /contribution_votes(.:format)     {:controller=>"contribution_votes", :action=>"destroy"}`